# unable to run a function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am new in `postgresql` and at the first I want to write a function in `postgresql`. I copied and paste an example from `pgsql` but an error occurred.
this is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunc() RETURNS integer AS $$
<< outerblock >>
DECLARE
    quantity integer := 30;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Quantity here is %', quantity;  -- Prints 30
    quantity := 50;
    --
    -- Create a subblock
    --
    DECLARE
        quantity integer := 80;
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Quantity here is %', quantity;  -- Prints 80
        RAISE NOTICE 'Outer quantity here is %', outerblock.quantity;  -- Prints 50
    END;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Quantity here is %', quantity;  -- Prints 50

    RETURN quantity;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and my error:

```
An error has occured
Fehler:Syntaxfehler bei "CREATE"
Line2:$Body$CREATE FUNCTION somefunc () RETURNS integer AS $$
```

**EDIT:**
I have written the above code in code section but psql generate already the same code in SQL section with additional Line:

```
$BODY$CREATE FUNCTION somefunc() RETURNS integer AS $$
```

and the error occurde in this line
[image]
if I delete this line, this error occured in the next line:
[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Did you try to remove the <<outerblock>> line?

Comment: How do you try to create function? copy and paste above code inside psql shell? or via \i /path/filename.pgsql?

Comment: I try to do that inside psql shell

Comment: You can take screenshorts of the window that is currently active (on top) by pressing alt+print screen :)

Comment: Why is there a `$BODY$` ***before*** the `create function`?

Comment: That `outerblock.quantity` seems strange. I don't think that is valid syntax.

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name. Why there's a `$BODY$` just before `CREATE`?

Comment: pgsql generate it automatically, you mean that I should delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are using a GUI to generate your function. If this is the case, then the GUI likely had fields like function name and parameters, which you filled in (or ignored). Where you are now entering code would therefore be the body area of the function, the GUI having already prompted you for all of the boilerplate information. If all of this is the case, then you should only include function body code in that field, instead of the full function creation code (because the application will be generating that for you based on what you input to the GUI).

Alternatively, if the application allows you to execute arbitrary SQL (it surely does), you could execute your CREATE as arbitrary SQL instead of using the GUI.